# Reading one large TXT file (out of multiple in a ZIP file) from a URL into a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, zip, text-files, dask

I have a list of 200+ URLs for ZIP files, each containing a bunch of large .txt files. I want to thread through these and read/manipulate relevant data from each.

Is there a fastest method to do this in Python 3.+? I've seen varying answers. At present the following works as a single-zip example (with a link):

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

def extract(zip_url, filename, colspecs, names):
     r = urlopen(zip_url).read()
     file = ZipFile(BytesIO(r))    
     df = pd.read_fwf(
         file.open(filename), 
         colspecs=colspecs, 
         names=names,
     )
     return df

# sample params corresponding to test url below
colspecs = [
    (1,3), (4,13), (14,14), (15,64), (65,75), (76,76), (77,77), (78,81),
    (82,83), (84,85), (86,86), (87,88), (89,91), (92,106), (107,110),
    (111,121), (122,125), (126,129), (130,131), (132,132), (133,134),
    (135,135), (136,146), (147,157), (158,182), (183,202), (203,222),
    (223,223), (224,234), (235,245), (246,246), (247,257), (258,268),
    (269,269), (270,270), (271,271), (272,282), (283,283), (284,284),
    (285,295), (296,325), (326,336), (337,366)
]
names = [i for i in range(len(colspecs))]

# test url
extract(zip_url="https://media.justice.gov/video/usao/data/YearPrevious2021/DISK01.zip", filename="gs_case.txt", colspecs=colspecs, names=names)
```

This method seems to be very slow, perhaps because of the number and size of txt files in each zip overall? Other answers point to dask potentially being faster. Might that be the case?

**Edit**

Line profiling output below for the sample `extract`:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 349.948 s
File: <ipython-input-26-8930e232e61f>
Function: extract at line 2

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     2                                           def extract(zip_url, colspecs=colspecs, names=names, filename="gs_case.txt"):
     3         1        506.0    506.0      0.0      print(zip_url)
     4         1   78720049.0 78720049.0     22.5      file = ZipFile(BytesIO(urlopen(zip_url).read()))    
     5         1  271227660.0 271227660.0     77.5      df = pd.read_fwf(file.open(filename), colspecs=colspecs, names=names)
     6         1        226.0    226.0      0.0      print(df.shape)
     7         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      return df
```

Comment: In the example you are reading one file out of the zip. Are you intending to read every file out of every zip?

Comment: @mdurant in this case there are multiple files in each zip, but no I'm only intending to read one file (with a common filename across zips) from each.

Comment: I recommend you profile to find out which is taking the bulk of the time: download, decompress or pandas parsing.

Comment: @mdurant thank you! Any chance you have tips on a tool to use to do such profiling in Python...?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/ via ipython magic `%lprun` and https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/ via `%snakeviz`

Comment: Thanks @mdurant, updated question with profile on that one call... wondering why the zip read takes over a minute at all, but anyway, the bulk of the time (~4+ minutes I suppose) for this single call is on the pandas read. Also not sure if this would be compounded by trying to thread multiple zips? Assuming I'd hit a memory limit with pandas here...

Comment: That line contains both decompress and parse, so it would be worth also running snakeviz.